# angular creating unwanted links

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-cli

I am using angular 4, with angular cli. With the default generated config files. The framework is generating unwanted anchor tags. I am trying to show this as plain text. This line inside my template.html:

```
someExampleSite.com
```

when served in the browser it becomes:

```
<a class="vglnk" href="http://someExampleSite.com" rel="nofollow">
 <span>someExampleSite</span>
 <span>.</span>
 <span>com</span>
</a>
```

Is there a way to get around this? I only want to display someExampleSite.com as plain text on the page.

Comment: are you *sure* that this is angular4 doing this, and not some browser plugin?

Comment: this is definitely not Angular behavior, I just spun up a new app to test, and cannot reproduce this.  The `vglnk` class seems to come from a link advertising service, VigLink.  From their site: "Through our process, we can scan content and find the commercial mentions. And, if any product mentions are unlinked, VigLink Insert hyperlinks them without the publisher doing anything."

Comment: i was able to resolve it by removing disqus from my page. When i selectively disabled scripts in firefox, I saw this behavior wasn't happening anymore.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem was being caused by disqus.

I unchecked both of the boxes in:
https://mysite.disqus.com/admin/settings/advanced/

Comment: I was looking for information about Disqus creating links, but found nothing relevant. Thanks to the `vglnk` class I get here.